# Fortran Error Meanings

Tags: error-handling, fortran, scientific-computing

I have been following books and PDFs on writing in FORTRAN to write an integration program. I compile the code with gfortran and get several copies of the following errors.

```
1)Unexpected data declaration statement at (1)
2)Unterminated character constant beginning at (1)
3)Unclassifiable statement at (1)
4)Unexpected STATEMENT FUNCTION statement at (1)
5)Expecting END PROGRAM statement at (1)
6)Syntax error in data declaration at (1)
7)Statement function at (1) is recursive
8)Unexpected IMPLICIT NONE statement at (1)
```

I do not know hat they truly mean or how to fix them, google search has proven null and the other topics on this site we about other errors. for Error 5) i put in Program main and end program main like i might in C++ but still got the same result.  Error 7) makes no sense, i am trying for recursion in the program. Error 8) i read implicit none was to prevent unnecessary decelerations.

Ill post the code itself but i am more interested in the compiling errors because i still need to fine tune the array data handling, but i cant do that until i get it working.

```
         Program main
  implicit none      
  real, dimension(:,:), allocatable :: m, oldm
  real a
  integer io, nn
  character(30) :: filename
  real, dimension(:,:), allocatable :: alt, temp, nue, oxy
  integer locationa, locationt, locationn, locationo, i
  integer nend
  real dz, z, integral
  real alti, tempi, nuei, oxyi
  integer y, j

  allocate( m(0, 0) ) ! size zero to start with?

  nn = 0
  j = 0

   write(*,*) 'Enter input file name: '

   read(*,*) filename

   open( 1, file = filename )



  do !reading in data file

   read(1, *, iostat = io) a

   if (io < 0 ) exit

   nn = nn + 1

   allocate( oldm( size(m), size(m) ) )

   oldm = m 

   deallocate( m )

   allocate( m(nn, nn) )

   m = oldm

   m(nn, nn) = a ! The nnth value of m

   deallocate( oldm )

  enddo



  ! Decompose matrix array m into column arrays [1,n]

  write(*,*) 'Enter Column Number for Altitude'
  read(*,*) locationa
  write(*,*) 'Enter Column Number for Temperature'
  read(*,*) locationt
  write(*,*) 'Enter Column Number for Nuetral Density'
  read(*,*) locationn 
  write(*,*) 'Enter Column Number for Oxygen density'
  read(*,*) locationo

  nend = size(m, locationa) !length of column #locationa

  do i = 1, nend

   alt(i, 1) = m(i, locationa)

   temp(i, 1) = log(m(i, locationt))

   nue(i, 1) = log(m(i, locationn))

   oxy(i, 1) = log(m(i, locationo))

  enddo



  ! Interpolate Column arrays, Constant X value will be array ALT with the 3 other arrays

  !real dz = size(alt)/100, z, integral = 0
  !real alti, tempi, nuei, oxyi
  !integer y, j = 0
  dz = size(alt)/100


  do z = 1, 100, dz
  y = z !with chopped rounding alt(y) will always be lowest integer for smooth transition.
  alti = alt(y, 1) + j*dz ! the addition of j*dz's allow for all values not in the array between two points of the array. 

   tempi = exp(linear_interpolation(alt, temp, size(alt), alti))

   nuei = exp(linear_interpolation(alt, nue, size(alt), alti))

   oxyi = exp(linear_interpolation(alt, oxy, size(alt), alti))
   j = j + 1



   !Integration

   integral = integral + tempi*nuei*oxyi*dz 

  enddo


  end program main


  !Functions

  real function linear_interpolation(x, y, n, x0)

   implicit none

   integer :: n, i, k

   real :: x(n), y(n), x0, y0

   k = 0


  do i = 1, n-1

   if ((x0 >= x(i)) .and. (x0 <= x(i+1))) then  

    k = i ! k is the index where: x(k) <= x <= x(k+1)
    exit ! exit loop

   end if

  enddo


  if (k > 0) then  ! compute the interpolated value for a point not in the array

   y0 = y(k) + (y(k+1)-y(k))/(x(k+1)-x(k))*(x0-x(k))

  else

   write(*,*)'Error computing the interpolation !!!'

   write(*,*) 'x0 =',x0, ' is out of range <', x(1),',',x(n),'>'

  end if

  ! return value

     linear_interpolation = y0

  end function linear_interpolation
```

I can provide a more detailed description of the exact errors, i was hoping that the error name would be enough since i have a few of each type.

Comment: Firstly, it usually only makes sense to look at the first error, because subsequent errors could be consequences of the first error. The numbers in brackets at the end of the error messages are important. They should also be accompanied by an annotated part of the code, with a corresponding number in brackets showing the place where the error occurred. This is the most important information which is missing from your question.

Comment: Ok so the first error in full is real, dimension(:), allocatable :: alt, temp, nue, oxy            
                                                                        1
Error: Unexpected data declaration statement at (1)
integration.f:28.72:

Comment: @DaveP is exactly right; it's best to approach this systematically.  Take a look at the first error.   The output surrounding that error refers to line 27 of your program and the (1) in question points to the end of the line.   In this case, the problem is that unlike a lot of programming languages, in Fortran you can't just define variables anywhere; they have to go at the start of a routine.   (There's a TS to change that for blocks, I think, but for now that's how it is).   So you have to move that line up to the other declarations.  Proceed like that, one bit at a time...

Comment: Thank you for that advice, i was able to clear quite a few errors but i still have a few, some new. the first to appear is tempi = exp(linear_interpolation(alt, temp, size(alt), alti)     
                                                                        1
Error: Syntax error in argument list at (1)
and i read that In FORTRAN, the maximal line length is
132 characters. Thus, you should split the lines. however i only have 60 with spaces. the second is that at all my do loop end decelerations the compiler says it expects end program not end do.

Comment: lastly which i may have fixed but since i am here will ask before compiling again is that i am getting oxyi = exp(linear_interpolation(alt, oxy, size(alt), alti)       
                                                                        1
Error: Syntax error in argument list at (1)
and so i added a 1 like, alt(i, 1), to make it two demensions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I can spot a few serious errors in your code sample. The syntax error is that you have unbalanced parentheses in the `exp(...` statements. They should be like this:

```
tempi = exp(linear_interpolation(alt, temp, size(alt), alti) ) ! <- extra ")"
nuei = exp(linear_interpolation(alt, nue, size(alt), alti) )
oxyi = exp(linear_interpolation(alt, oxy, size(alt), alti) )
```

It's precisely things like this that can produce long strings of confusing errors like you're getting; therefore the advice Dave and Jonathan have given can't be repeated often enough.

Another error (the "unclassifiable statement") applies to your loops:

```
do(i=1, nend)
! ...
do(z=1, 100, dz)
! ...
```

These should be written without parentheses.

The "data declaration error" stems from your attempt to declare and initialise multiple variables like

```
real dz = size(alt)/100, z, integral = 0
```

Along with being positioned incorrectly in the code (as noted), this can only be done with the double colon separator:

```
real :: dz = size(alt)/100, z, integral = 0
```

I personally recommend always writing declarations like this. It must be noted, though, that initialising variables like this has the side effect of implicitly giving them the `save` attribute. This has no effect in a main program, but is important to know; you can avoid it by putting the initialisations on a separate line.

Comment: Yea i finally saw the missing parentheses sometime last night. Took a swing at the do loop parentheses but that last thing using real :: that is very helpful it condenses my code, i just declared and initialized them separately and it worked the same. no i think i am getting logic errors; allocate( oldm( size(m) ) )
                                1
Error: Syntax error in specification at (1). the only thing i can think is that i am moving through the file in the wrong way to obtain the appropriate n x m matrix. from the file.

Comment: Well, I didn't check the logic very closely, but there is nothing inherently wrong with such an allocation statement. It would help the diagnosis if you could update your code listing, since the existing code is clearly not compilable.

Comment: Updated the code in the original post and well the errors i am getting are do z = 1, 100, dz (1) REAL loop variable at (1) - to enable REAL loop parameters use -freal-loops and Rank mismatch in array reference (1/2). The first i know it is trying to tell me i cant do small "real" increments with first adding something, but i cant find what that is. The second i know is because my arrays are not the same dimensions, but i am trying to go from a two dimensional matrix to multiple single dimension arrays that come from the columns of that matrix.

Comment: Yes, you have defined `z` and `dz` as reals. Using those for loop control can give unpredictable results due to the limited floating point precision. They are no longer standard Fortran since F95; you should use integers and convert these to real within the loop if needed. As for array indexing, you can simply obtain a column vector from a matrix as `matrix(:, col_idx)`.